# How to get a retrieve a string from a tuple directly?

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
class Card:
    def __init__(self, suit):
        self.suit = SUITS[suit]
    SUITS = ("HEARTS", "SPADES", "DIAMONDS", "CLUBS")
```

Is there anyway to directly access only one of these four values from the tuple and store it? so that i can make a new object of type Card and then set its suit, only to one of the four values in the tuple.

i would like to take a string as the input parameter e.g myCard = Card(HEARTS)

Comment: You mean like, `SUITS[2]` `SUITS[3]` or something else?

Comment: yes but i would like to take a string as the input parameter e.g myCard = Card(HEARTS)

Comment: You should have mentioned that you want to accept strings in your `__init__()`, or you should have provided an example usage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can validate against SUITS.
If invalid suit given, may you raise a `ValueError`

```
class Card:
    SUITS = ("HEARTS", "SPADES", "DIAMONDS", "CLUBS")
    def __init__(self, suit):
        if suit not in self.SUITS:
             raise ValueError('invalid argument suit. must be: {}'.format(
                  ', '.join(self.SUITS)
             ))
        self.suit = suit
```

One can now create an instance by

```
burp = Card('SPADES')
```

Another way could be to use [Enum's](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html) here:

```
from enum import Enum
class Suits(Enum):
    HEARTS = 0
    SPADES = 1
    DIAMONDS = 2
    CLUBS = 3

class Card:
    def __init__(self, suit):
        assert(type(suit) is Suits)
        self.suit = suit

snurz = Card(Suits.CLUBS)
```

Comment: is there any other way without throwing an error? e.g not specifying but by default python will throw it?

Comment: I prefer this, because I can define clean messages, so developers (including myself) get some hints whats going on when something went wrong (what valid values are available). I don't know if one can force python directly to raise an exception if an element is not in a list. You could do something like this: `self.suit = dict({k:True for k in self.SUITS})[self.suit]` but its kinda crypto and the error could be misleading.

Comment: You can use assert. Watch my second example. Also you can use that in first example: `assert(suit in self.SUITS)`

Answer (score 1):

Within your class you need to prefix `SUITS` with `Card` (or `self`) like this:

```
class Card:
    def __init__(self, suit):
        self.suit = Card.SUITS[suit]    # N.B. specify the class
    SUITS = ("HEARTS", "SPADES", "DIAMONDS", "CLUBS")

>>> for i in range(len(Card.SUITS)):
...     c = Card(i)
...     print(c.suit)
HEARTS
SPADES
DIAMONDS
CLUBS
```

I wouldn't bother with validating the `suit` argument; if an invalid value is supplied `Card.SUITS[suit]` will raise `IndexError` if it is out of range, or `TypeError` if a non-integer argument is supplied. You could catch either exception and raise your own, if you wanted.

Comment: class Card:
        def __init__(self, suit):
            self.suit = Card.SUITS[suit]    # N.B. specify the class
        SUITS = ("HEARTS", "SPADES", "DIAMONDS", "CLUBS")

    for i in range(len(Card.SUITS)):
        c = Card("SPADES")
        print(c.suit)

im not sure but its not working 

could u give me an example

Comment: OP has specified in a comment that `__init__()` should accept strings representing suit, invalidating this answer.

Comment: @Mark: the for loop is the example usage. But, as I said in previous comment, this answer is invalidated by the additional string argument requirement.

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to assign `self.suit` to the given name if the value is among the acceptable ones and otherwise assign it to a default value

```
>>> class Card:
...     SUITS = {"HEARTS", "SPADES", "DIAMONDS", "CLUBS"} # you can still use the tuple if you prefer
...     def __init__(self, suit):
...         self.suit = suit if suit in self.SUITS else 'HEARTS' # default_value
... 
>>> c=Card('abc')
>>> c.suit
'HEARTS'
>>> c=Card('DIAMONDS')
>>> c.suit
'DIAMONDS'
```

Note: I agree with @keksnicoh's approach (upvoted), which raises an exception.

Another way can be to pass the default value as a parameter as well (explicit is better than implicit, remember?)

```
>>> class Card:
...     SUITS = ("HEARTS", "SPADES", "DIAMONDS", "CLUBS")
...     def __init__(self, suit, default='HEARTS'):
...         self.suit = suit if suit in self.SUITS else default
... 
>>> c=Card('abc')
>>> c.suit
'HEARTS'
>>> c=Card('abc', 'DIAMONDS')
>>> c.suit
'DIAMONDS'
```

However, you should still check if the default values is among the possible values and at that point raise and exception (or add it to them, depending on your goals)